# CFFORM tag adding extra line in banner

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, comments

When I have add this  tag I get an extra line in one of my banners. It's twice as wide as all of the other 3 on the page. It's about the size of 2 lines of output.

Code:

```
<CFAJAXIMPORT tags="cfform" />
<CFFORM NAME="disclosureExportForm" />
```

Attempted solutions: 
`<!--<CFFORM NAME="disclosureExportForm" />-->`
I tried to comment out the tag with an HTML tag since an HTML comment isn't the same as a ColdFusion comment. It fixed the issue of the extra line, but it resulted in an error `ColdFusion.Ajax.submitform: Form not found, form id: disclosureExportForm`

What I'm looking for is if there's a way to include the tag without it affecting any of the elements on the page.

Edit:

I also tried just using the FORM tag, but it didn't make a difference. Any guesses?

Comment: Can you give us the generated HTML of the with and without? (Not everything, but enough to see what the difference is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion has "issues" with white space management.  Give this article a look:

http://ray.camdenfamily.com/index.cfm/2006/7/26/ColdFusion-Whitespace-Options

Comment: Excellent article, thanks! Just a question, will using <cfsilent> interfere with the <cfform> tag other than suppressing the output?

Comment: Not that I know of but I do know for certain.   Best of luck!

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll find out when QS tests it. haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might actually be the CFAJAXIMPORT rather than the CFFORM. Try removing the CFAJAXIMPORT and see if that fixes things. Other than that, try looking at the output in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see if maybe its an issue with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try if

```
<cfform name="disclosureExportForm" style="margin-bottom: 0;" />
```

solves your problem.